# How can I set onClick listeners for the options in my List preference?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclicklistener

I have a list preference that will allow a user to select which audio codec they wish to use in my Voice Recorder android application.

I would like to set an onClick listener for each item in the list as when it is selected I need to access my main activity and change the MediaRecorder's settings. Currently, I have an onClick listener that only activates when the "Audio Codec" option itself is selected.

[Here is my preference activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re2ie.png) and below is the current code for the onClick listerner.

```
final Preference audioCodec = findPreference("codec");
   audioCodec.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
          System.out.println("Clicked");
          return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Below are the values that I want the onClick listener to be assigned to rather than just the title "Audio Codec". Is this possible?

```
<!-- Audio codec list  -->
<string-array name="codecListArray">
    <item>Audio codec 1</item>
    <item>Audio codec 2</item>
    <item>Audio codec 3</item>
</string-array>
```

Please let me know if you need more screenshots or information, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `OnPreferenceChangeListener` that is triggered each time the preference is changed.

```
audioCodec.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {    
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        // newValue is the value you choose
        return true;
    }
});
```